# Default focus left column upon start

Tags: sublimetext3

If I start Sublimetext3 (on Ubuntu19.10) either via its launcher icon or via a file I want to edit, the file is automatically loaded into the right column of my 2 column layout. Is there a configuration option where I can change this behaviour so it shows the files in the **left** column, or if ST3 is started directly, puts the cursor in the left column? (I'd like to keep the 2 column layout because I normally have the R Repl in the right column)

## Edit:

I am on (K)Ubuntu 19.10 (should have included that in the beginning)

The suggested solution [here](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/unable-to-save-column-layout-in-st3/33829/10) (using the plugin system) is going into the right direction but I was not able to set it up so it does what I'd like it to do ;)

If open a file with sublimetext3, it still loads the file in the right pane and then after some delay switches the focus to the left... If I start ST3 not via a file but with a launcher the behavior is almost as desired (except the delay)

Comment: How did you set up a default layout of 2 columns? Perhaps that can be extended to also change the focus to file group 0.

Comment: @OdatNurd Thank you for your comment! That got me thinking ;) I don't actually *set* the default layout but rely on ST3s behaviour on linux to re-open new windows with the same layout as when ST3 was closed the last time. Exactly as you (or soemeone with the same handle ;) ) are describing [here](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/unable-to-save-column-layout-in-st3/33829/10).  I have to admit, I never even thought about it that way (saving a default) and was only looking for answers how to set the a focus, since comming from ST2 that seemed to be the problem to me ... go figure  ;)

Comment: @OdatNurd If I may: I followed your suggestion and I can it almost get to work, but it still loads the file in the right pane and then after some delay switches the focus to the left... If I start ST3 not via a file but with a launcher the behavior is almost  as desired (except the delay) Maybe if you could share your insights into this approach or nudge me in the right direction for good ressources on the plugin system ? I never dove that deep into ST3s innards ;) But thanks anyways! If you add an answer with the content of your comment (or even more ideas/insights) I will gladly accept it!

Comment: Sorry, been busy and haven't had a chance to peek in recently. I suspect that the issue you're having here is that the plugin host is started after Sublime starts and becomes ready at some point after that (so as to not delay startup until plugins are ready). The behaviour you're describing here (the focus shifting after a bit) seems like a symptom of that. Some potential plugin changes may resolve the issue, though. I'm testing some stuff currently.

Comment: @OdatNurd Don't worry, its not a time critical feature ;) Of the two "less than ideal situations" the first (loading files into the right pane) is more annoying to me than the later (opening 'empty' ST3 client with focus shifted after a short delay). But I might also consider changing my workflow and starting always with a 1 column layout (2nd column is only a shortcut away anyways). To get to know (of) the ST3 plugin system was it alone almost worth asking the question here and I can't always get what I want ;) Thank you so much for your time and support!

Comment: As far as I can tell, the command to change the layout from 1 to 2 columns will always put the focus on the right, so the plugin needs to be extended to flip the focus to the left too. It sounds like you sort of have something like that already though, since it's happening at an inopportune time.